# Having trouble writing HGLOBAL DIB data to file

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I'm using a capture card dll which exports a function that provides an HGLOBAL handle containing a DIB.  I want to write this DIB to a file.   After I lock the resource and retrieve the data pointer, I request the size and it's about 1mb.  But then when I write it to a file, it's always 0 bytes.  This is the first time I've worked with an HGLOBAL type so I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong.  I appreciate your help.

```
char* dibData = (char*)LockResource(DIB);
if(NULL != dibData)
{
    SIZE_T dibSize = GlobalSize (DIB);
    f = fopen("thedib.dib", "wb");

    if (f)
    {
        n = fwrite(dibData,dibSize,1,f);
        fflush(f);
        fclose(f);
        wrote = true;
    }

    UnlockResource(DIB);
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `SizeofResource(DIB)`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048.aspx

Comment: If I do DWORD dibSize = SizeofResource (NULL,(HRSRC)DIB); then dibsize=0.

Comment: I'm wondering if LockResource is even necessary because this image is not coming from an executable.

Comment: I guess the natural question is how/where did you get DIB from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be mixing resource APIs and global memory APIs.  If it's really a resource, use LockResource(), SizeofResource(), UnlockResource().  If it's just a memory block allocated via GlobalAlloc(), use GlobalLock(), GlobalSize(), GlobalUnlock().

Also, a .bmp file should start with a `BITMAPFILEHEADER` structure.  This structure is not present for in-memory DIBs, so you need to write that structure prior to writing your DIB data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If I do `DWORD dibSize = SizeofResource (NULL,(HRSRC)DIB);` then dibsize=0.  If I fix this problem, I will be sure to write the bitmap header.

Comment: Set a breakpoint just after LockResource (should be GlobalLock ?) and inspect the memory pointed to by `dibData`.  If it's a valid DIB, the first DWORD will be 40 (0x28 hex) which is the size of the BITMAPINFOHEADER.

Comment: I used GlobalLock and that fixed the problem.  Thanks